# Was there an influence of Schellings Naturphilosophie on Einstein?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, schelling

Darrigol in *Electrodynamics from Ampere to Einstein* writes:

> In Germany, a few marginal followers of Schellings *Naturphilosophie* criticised the general notion of fluids acting at a distance and sought a deeper unity of nature that would relate apparently disconnected phenomena. They favoured a dynamistic, anti-Newtonian view of physical interactions in which matter and force was not distinguished. Matter was only a balance of two opposing forces and every action at a distance was to be reduced to a propagating disturbance or polarity of this balance.

This appears to be clearly related to speculations by William Clifford on space and matter. For example, in a paper read out to the Cambridge Philsophical Society in 1870 he said:

> 1. That small portions of space are in fact of a nature analogous to
>      little hills on a surface which is on the average flat; namely, that
>      the ordinary laws of geometry are not valid in them.
> 2. That this property of being curved or distorted is continually being
>      passed from one portion of space to another after the manner of
>      a wave.
> 3. That this variation of the curvature of space is what really happens
>      in that phenomenon which we call the motion of matter, whether
>      ponderable or etherial.
> 4. That in the physical world nothing else takes place but this variation,
>      subject (possibly) to the law of continuity.”

The resemblence here is quite clear as is the resemblence to GR. There are also some speculations by Newton where he pondered the ponderability of atoms and suggested that they were merely the balance of forces.

Its generally taken that Mach had a large influence on Einstein, on his own admittance. However there is a clear resemblence between what these followers of Schelling argued for and that of the theory of gravity put forward by Einstein, that one might argue for an indirect or direct influence. Was there? And if so, why has this particular tradition been down-played in the history and philosophy of physics?

According to Keith Richardson on a discussion of Schellings philosophy

> [His] early philosophy of nature met opposition in part because its ethical and political interests—not just its allegedly wild and “unverifiable” analogizing—were thought to have invalidated its “scientific” claims.

If this is the case, what were specifically Schellings ethical & political interests that caused his philosophy to become neglected?

Comment: I do not see it. Clifford's theory is not a "dynamistic, anti-Newtonian view of physical interactions" but a typical continualist Newtonian proposal of a kind with ether theories. He uses the curvature of space instead of ether characteristics as the primary field variable, but that is hardly holistic naturphilosophie stripped of the "maze of calculations" that Schelling wanted. Maxwell replacing action at a distance with continuous fields also had more to do with Faraday's experiments than with German romanticism.

Comment: @conifold: Clifford says that there is no matter except a balance of forces which he characterises as curvature; this is wholly dynamic. Its not Newtonian matter moving in a space. I'm not the only one to see this, for example Clifford was inspired by Riemann, and according to [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0969725X.2016.1229417?src=recsys&journalCode=cang20) essay published in the *Journal of Theoretical Humanities*, Riemann was under the influence of  Schellings *Naturphilosophie*, as was Jacobi, Listing & Grassmann.

Comment: I'm not saying by this that Clifford was directly influenced by Schelling, by the way.

Comment: Riemann named his influences on geometry, Herbart (Kant's successor in Königsberg) and Gauss. He probably read some about early Schelling in Herbart, and absorbed some more by cultural osmosis in Göttingen. But his geometric ideas are transparently derived from Kantian intuition of space and Gauss's theory of surfaces. Reducing matter to formations of ether was a commonality in 19-th century, and (Newtonian) fluid dynamics was the underlying theory. Clifford combined Riemann's and  Maxwell's ideas, if there was some naturphilosophic influence in there it was very atmospheric.

Comment: @conifold: Nevertheless there are other people besides myself who think that there is a possible influence. The thesis of Marie-Louise Heuser is ' Schelling’s philosophy of the emergence of space can be read in Riemannian terms'. I'm not denying that there are other sources of influence, such as Kant. And besides Kant was a strong infleunce on Schelling.

Comment: Heuser's historical source on Riemann, Scholz, writes:"*Riemann's knowledge of certain aspects of Fichte's and Schelling's dialectical philosophy came through his studies of Herbart, although Riemann was not directly influenced by their philosophy.*" And Heuser herself writes that Riemann's extractions from Herbart show him interested "*in
the small number of passages on Fichte’s and Schelling’s theory of the ego*", not naturphilosophie. In fact, there is no textual support in the paper for the claim that Riemann's geometric ideas "had something to do" with Schelling.

Comment: Riemann wrote his own essay on naturphilosophie, where he says he was "*led to it by the study of the works of Newton, Euler, and on the other side, Herbart*". Actually, Mach in his youth was also a Herbartian, and later credited his relativistic ideas to Herbart's "*construction of intelligible space*", which relativized and psychologized Kant's pure intuition, see [Banks](https://philpapers.org/archive/BANKHA.pdf). So if you are looking for an inspirational philosophical source of Einstein's geometrodynamics of gravity it would be Herbart.

Comment: @conifold: Herbart wrote three essays on Schellings philosophy, before he became critical of it. So it seems to me Schelling was an influence. Heuser also maintains that most of the physicists that adhered to fields as an explanatory device were under the influence of Schelling. Riemann in a posthumous fragment admitted he was influenced by Herbart, but not by his ontology.

Comment: Of course Schelling was, on young Herbart (although he was more of a Fichtean). Riemann ignored his naturphilosophie, and in geometry followed Herbart's (Kantian) psychology. For that matter, so did later Herbart, it is his break with German idealism that made his philosophy attractive to Riemann and Mach (see Scholz). Be mindful of Heuser, she writes a lot of fluff and pays little attention to even her own references. It is curious that this essay was published in JTH where reviewers would not be experts on history of geometry and physics.

Comment: @Conifold: At least she's published. Have you published anything I can look up in a peer-revised journal?

Comment: @conifold: or is self-publishing these days considered peer-review?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to keep the air of mystery as they phrase it here :) In this case you do not need me anyway, just look at Banks and Scholz.

Comment: @conifold: some prefer mystery whilst others are sceptical...

Comment: @conifold: to put it bluntly - I'm sceptical.

Comment: This article is interesting on Einstein's philosophical roots: https://www.britannica.com/story/what-einstein-meant-by-god-does-not-play-dice

Answer (score 0):

The view that matter is the balance of forces was originally advanced by Kant in his 1786 *Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science* in the chapter devoted to *Dynamics* but, indeed, it was taken up by the German *Naturphilosophie* movement.

Schelling and his followers definitely had some significant influence on the subsequent mathematics, philosophy and physics, ex. on Hermann von Helmholtz (who nevertheless distanced himself from "unscientific" philosophies of Schelling and Hegel - which I think is quite unfair towards both Schelling and Hegel, especially given that many of Schelling's followers were themselves practicing natural scientists) and Hermann Grassmann.

However, I'd expect, in terms of ideas like these, the influence of Kant to  be much greater. Einstein, it seems, didn't fully appreciate Kant's philosophy of science (although he supposedly read three *Critiques* as a teenager) but nevertheless, through Poincare, Hertz, Mach and Helmholtz, was significantly influenced by it. There are some specific interesting convergences between Kant's and Einstein's ideas which I discussed [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/110752/73173).