# Is is true that Kant's philosophy inspired Einstein's theory of relativity?

Tags: kant, history

Could you explain how it did inspire Einstein, and if Einstein gave him any credit for any of his ideas?

Comment: Einstein himself wrote that Hume and Mach were his philosophical inspirations.  See, for example, [How Hume and Mach Helped Einstein Find Special Relativity](https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/HumeMach.pdf).

Comment: no idea, but i've seen it said that kant was obnoxiously / very right about a lot of things he had no idea but

Comment: Not in any direct way. Einstein credited Mach for philosophical inspiration, and one can find some vague affinity between Kant's philosophy of physics and some of Mach's ideas. As for direct "credit", [Norton](https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_GR_geometry/Einstein_on_Kant.html) calls what Einstein wrote on synthetic a priori "*a thinly veiled repudiation of Kant. The veil would have been all but completely transparent to Einstein's German language readers*". [Weinert](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4619681) is more charitable.

Comment: Einstein was a nobody promoted by the oligarchs so they can hide true practical physics from the world in favor of good for movies only theories that eventually deployed a deep fog over the true physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirectly.

It’s perhaps not so well known that Gauss was inspired by Kant to theorise non-Euclidean Geometry. Riemann was a student of Gauss and was inspired to come up with the general notion of Riemannian manifolds. This was definitely enough for Clifford to hypothesise that forces are, essentially, waves in space. Einstein as well as Nordstrom took up this technology to theorise gravity in a geometrical form. This notion has spread to all the other forces, so we generally think of forces as geometrical in some way or another.

It’s possible to speculate, in the way that the modern notion of atoms has its antecedent in Democritean atoms, that the modern notion of waves is due to Thales thinking of the world as water.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned:

1. Through the influence of Kant on XIX-th century mathematics, notably Gauss and Riemann, but also Klein, (Hermann) Grassmann, Poincare (also physicist) and Helmholtz (who was also a physicist and a physiologist). Some of them also were influenced by German Idealism (notably, Grassmann).
2. Through the influence of Kant on XIX-th century physicists. He influenced, among others, Hertz, Helmholtz, Mach and Poincare.
3. Through his influence on philosophy of science more generally. Einstein notes: *I did not grow up in the Kantian tradition, but came to understand the truly valuable which is to be found in his doctrine... quite late. It is contained in the sentence: the real is not given to us, but is put to us by way of a riddle.* Although his statement suggests that he didn't originally recognize the idea in Kant (who he read as a teenager), he nevertheless certainly was familiar with it through other sources (as Kantian thought was particularily influential at that time). Einstein [read and discussed works on physics and philosophy with his friends around 1902](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia_Academy).

But there is also a deeper connection between Einstein's and Kant's theories of physics:

1. Kant begins his *Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science* by deriving the law of invariance under Galilean transformations. As David J. Hyder brilliantly argues in his paper *Kant on Time I*, this proof is based on Euclid's *Mechanics* from 1736. Kant reverses the order of the proof, deriving from the conclusion, given some further premises, the original premise of Euler's proof. The same derivation, albeit within hyperbolic geometry, is found in Einstein's 1905 paper which introduces Special Relativity. And this, of course, means that the relevant transformations are Lorenzian, not Galilean.
2. As Hyder argues [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAVeZuvQ6sk), there is also a significant similarity between Kant's account of time-determinations in his *Analytic of Principles* of the first *Critique* and Einstein's causal understanding of time as illustrated by the [EPR paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Podolsky%E2%80%93Rosen_paradox).

Another significant connection is with the notion of **geometrization** which is a common view on what constitutes the "essence" of the Theory of Relativity (albeit, I believe, unsupported by Einstein himself). This is a "trivial" way of resolving some tensions which arise in Kant's theory of geometry (on that see Hyder's *The Determinate World*) in the light of the contingent nature of physical geometry (as opposed to Kant's view that it's *a priori* in a very strict sense). Thomas Ryckman discusses Kantian influence on some physicists in this regard in the epilogue to his work: *The Reign of Relativity*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is enough historical evidence to say that Kant inspired the theory of relativity. Einstein read all 3 of Kant's critiques at the age of 16, before he published his relativity papers. Einstein was also influenced by Hume and Schopenhauer. Hegel type philosophy did not interest him.

For Einstein, space and time are central, just as they were for Kant. Also, Ernst Mach was a Kantian philosopher / physicist, whom Einstein took very seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Oh course, one reads different takes on this. Eistein took philosophy seriously, particularly Kant's philosophy, and here Einstein was going to overturn a part of Kant. This was a big deal for Einstein, a big step.

To get some idea of how this played out you may want to see Prof Norton's website, Einstein on Kant:  [https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_GR_geometry/Einstein_on_Kant.html](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_GR_geometry/Einstein_on_Kant.html)